# Creating a list with data from a Dataframe index in Python

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, datareader

i'm facing troubles trying to convert the index of df (see code) into a list, because when i run it this list is a "Timestamp" one (i dont know what that means). The code is

```
quote='AAPL'
stock = DataReader(quote,'yahoo',start_date,end_date)
stock.head()
df=DataFrame(stock)
xdata = df.index.tolist()
```

And then when run i get

```
[Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2010-01-05 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2010-01-06 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2010-01-07 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2010-01-08 00:00:00')]
```

But i want to have something like this:

```
['2010-01-04', '2010-01-05'), ...,'2010-01-08')]
```

Can somebody please help me out with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `df.index.map(pd.Timestamp.date).tolist()` or `df.index.date.tolist()`

Comment: TimeStamp is pandas dtype that is similar to numpy's datetime64, you'd be better off keeping the index as is, because when you want to do some datetime related operations such as find me the rows between 2 timestamps or min/max you will not be able to do this if you convert to a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
ts_list = df.index.tolist()  # a list of Timestamp's
date_list = [ ts.date() for ts in ts_list ]  # a list of datetime.date's
date_str_list = [ str(date) for date in date_list ]  # a list of strings
```