# Trying to return list of indexes after resampling

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to convert indexes in a dataframe to a list. The indexes are dates that have been resampled to 10min timeframes.

I have tried data.index.tolist()
but this returns:

```
    [Timestamp('2019-03-27 12:20:00'), Timestamp('2019-03-27 12:30:00'), 
    Timestamp('2019-03-27 12:40:00'), Timestamp('2019-03-27 12:50:00')]
```

Also data.index.values.tolist() returns:

```
[1553689200000000000, 1553689800000000000, 1553690400000000000, 1553691000000000000]
```

My code is as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_data.decode('utf-8')), header=0, 
names=['timestamp', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'],
index_col=0, parse_dates=True)

data = df.resample('10min').agg({'open': 'first', 
                                  'high': 'max', 
                                   'low': 'min', 
                                 'close': 'last', 
                                'volume': 'sum'}).dropna()

time = data.index.tolist()
```

There is probably a simple answer to this, but I just want a list of dates. I do not want Timestamp() or any of the meta data. Output should look like:

```
['2019-03-27 12:20:00', '2019-03-27 12:30:00', '2019-03-27 12:40:00', '2019-03-27 12:50:00']
```

Comment: See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478773/creating-a-list-with-data-from-a-dataframe-index-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
from datetime import datetime
dt_list = map(datetime.fromtimestamp,data.index.values.tolist())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `to_series`, `.dt` accessor, and `strftime`:

Setup dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,25).reshape(5,-1), 
                  index = pd.date_range('2018-03-12', periods=5, freq='D'))
```

Code:

```
df.index.to_series().dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').tolist()
```

Output:

```
['2018-03-12 00:00:00',
 '2018-03-13 00:00:00',
 '2018-03-14 00:00:00',
 '2018-03-15 00:00:00',
 '2018-03-16 00:00:00']
```